# How to retrieve a List of JSON Objects

Tags: java, json, rest, serialization

I get a list of Json Objects when I access this URI:

personUri = https://myuri.com/get/listOfPeople/

*JSON*

```
[{"firstName":"Tom","lastName":"Blue"},{"firstName":"Susan","lastName":"Summers"},{"firstName":"Albert","lastName":"Smith"}]
```

Java:

```
List<People>persons = new ArrayList<>();
UriComponentsBuilder componentsBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(personUri);
String jsonInfo = getRestTemplate().getForEntity(componentsBuilder.toUriString(), String.class).getBody();
LOG.debug("REST RESPONSE: "+jsonInfo);
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type=new TypeToken<List<People>>(){}.getType();
persons=gson.fromJson(jsonInfo,type);
```

I get this error.
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 62

Is this because I need to use HashMap.class instead of String.class?

VO

```
public class People {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

}

Comment: what does your `LOG.debug("REST RESPONSE: "+jsonInfo);` display? Because the error message is telling that the json is not valid (for a list)

Comment: Please post your People class

Comment: I think you should use Object[].class as `responseType` parameter, as I can see the JSON you are trying to use (I don't have access to that URL).

Comment: Ok.  Will try with Object Class.

Comment: The URL you shared is giving HTML content in response but not a valid JSON response. @spring_hiber

Comment: @Coder It can still be converted to a list of People objects. (whether the response is application/json or application/html is irrelevant)

Comment: @dsp_user RestTemplate makes use of Jackson serializer by default and I highly doubt it is capable of handling HTML data